# Leak at hot water valve, brand new valve and installed by pro

Tags: leak, hot-water

The valve is new. The hose is new. I made sure the valve for the hot water was off as well because I Never use hot water to wash my clothes in AZ. It actually looks like the water from the washer is being pushed back out on the hot water side valve... Any ideas?

Comment: it would not be pushed backwards . the problem is with new installation

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what you are hooking up to what (sounds like a washer is involved?) and what each of the valves you refer to controls? Please post photos of the area that is leaking.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If the pro has just done it, get them back to sort it.

Comment: what exactly is your question? ... `Any ideas?` is not very specific